# How do I detect whether the current accessibility setting in the OS

Tags: accessibility

I need to detect the accessibility setting in order to modify the UI at run time to support all the accessibility requirement.
I would like to know how can I detect whether the OS is currently in HIGH CONTRAST mode, and what is the current font size setting.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm guessing that you mean *beyond* using the system colors and fonts?

Comment: Is this for a particular OS/language?

Comment: hi,
I need to support windows , Linux and Mac.  I am using javascript displaying my text within a WebBrowser object. But this WebBrowser is located within an Eclipse plugin based rich client.  I have to manually adjust the font size based on the OS setting to support these accessibility requirement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is going to be to allow your users to select their own themes and then just make a number of them available. Typically, most OSs don't make accessibility information available in the same way, and there are *LOTS* of ways that users can adjust their displays to meet their own needs that don't go through the "normal" OS accessibility features (such as limiting the number of colors or resolution on their display)